# SQLite.Swift Expression() initialization for "not null" form?

Tags: sqlite.swift

Please note that this question ONLY relates to the popular `SQLite.swift` library, stephencelis/SQLite.swift

With SQLite.swift you can

```
    let a = Expression<String>("a")
    let b = Expression<String>("b")
```

and so on. But how do you

```
select a.x, a.y, ifnull(b.q, 'default text'), a.z
from a
left join b on blah
```

how do you make an expression for an inline sql ifnull clause?

(The doco mentions that Expression has an init(literal:) initializer - maybe it's relevant - but it's undocumented and has unusual binding arguments.)

Please note, I'm completely aware that you could make the value optional

```
  let q = Expression<String?>("q")
```

and then just put in the default later;

I am asking how to express "ifnull(b.q, 'default text')" as an Expression (or, learn it is impossible) so that value will actually be used in the SQL expression.

Once again, this question relates only to the library /stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: Well, a simple search for "ifnull" in the [SQLite.swift documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#sqliteswift-documentation) gives something.

Comment: Hey @GwendalRoué - thanks, but indeed, that line on the doco page doesn't at all explain how, or if, you can use a complex inline select expression. (eg, **select  ifnull(b.q, 'default text'), blah, blah**...)  Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere - perhaps it's just not handled.

Comment: So I guess you had to use raw SQL. In another project you may like to give GRDB.swift a try, as a replacement for SQLite.swift. The GRDB query builder has "holes" as well, and it can't generate all SQL queries. But at least you are not "punished" when you have to fallback to raw SQL: row consumption is identical.

Comment: Thanks! You'll try GRDB later ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dislike answering my own question,

but honestly the realistic answer here is:

nowadays you have to use GRDB like everyone else, github.com/groue/GRDB.swift

The older SQL-wrapper libraries (as magnificent, awesome, incredible as they were at the time) are honestly just

- totally out of date now, technology-wise
- not honestly maintained realistically any more

As of late 2017 GRDB is the only real possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too late, but anyway. I've checked the source code, there is function

```
public func ??<V : Value>(optional: Expression<V?>, defaultValue: V) -> Expression<V> {
    return "ifnull".wrap([optional, defaultValue])
}
```

So you have to make the value optional

```
row.get(Expression<Double?>("q")) ?? 0 //this will be equals ifnull(q, 0)
```